# What is the mime type to use for JSON Web Encryption

Tags: json, mime-types, rfc, jwe

Looking at [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) and [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516), I was trying to understand what the proper mime type for the JWE should be. It looks like JWE and JWS share the JOSE header information, and JWS defines its mime type as `application/jose`. JWE has no explicit media type information. But since the name is "jose" and both use JOSE header, I assume both should use the same mime type (also because JOSE stands for ... Signing and Encryption).

In this case, how do I differentiate between signed and/or encrypted messages? By value of the `alg` property? Or by presence/value of `enc` property?

To summarize:

1. Is "application/jose" a mime type to use for JWE? If not, then what should it be?
2. If yes, how to reliably tell between JWE and JWS messages?

Comment: [RFC7519#section-10.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-10.3.1) indicates the mime type is `application/jwt`.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli That's for JWT, my concern was between JWE and JWS only.

Comment: There is no mime type to distinguish JWS and JWE. It is up to the service that receive the token to handle the token type (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516#section9 you mentioned)

Comment: In any case, nothing prevents you from using your own mime type

Comment: What's the difference between `application/jwt` and `application/jose`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I only paid more attention to the [original RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516), I would have noticed that there is a section for this particular purpose ([section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-9)).

In short, the code should examine presence of `payload`, `ciphertext` or `enc` properties, or by checking the value of `alg`. Alternatively, count period separators if compact serialization is used.

This also implies that the mime type for both is the same.